# I have an error creating a role in MySQL in Phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I ran this command

```
CREATE ROLE
kaitech_admin,
product_manager,
sales_manager,
customer_service_representative;
```

but phpmyadmin will just return an error saying "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax"

However, I also tried doing this:

```
CREATE ROLE
kaitech_admin;
```

but still i get the same error.
What should i do?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? Roles were added in 8.0.

Comment: You can check the version of the MySQL Server with this query: `SELECT VERSION();` (i.e. the syntax support is not based on the version of the phpmyadmin client).